# Related products URL

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm trying to display related products in the product view page. I created a collection of them but when i try to fetch them, the getName() method renders the correct name but getProductUrl() renders the url of the parent product.
Here is my code:

```
  $categoryId = array_shift($_product->getCategoryIds());
  $related_prods = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addUrlRewrite($categoryId)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$_product->getRelatedProductIds()))->load();
  <div>
  <?php foreach($related_prods as $related){ ?>
  <a href="<?php  $this->getUrl('books').$related->getUrlPath()."<br />";?>"><?php echo $related->getName();?></a>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to load the product to get product url

```
 $categoryId = array_shift($_product->getCategoryIds());
      $related_prods = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addUrlRewrite($categoryId)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$_product->getRelatedProductIds()))->load();
      <div>
      <?php foreach($related_prods as $related){ 
    $related=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($related->getId());
    ?>
      <a href="<?php  echo $this->getUrl('books').$related->getUrlPath()."<br />";?>"><?php echo $related->getName();?></a>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: I have another question:
I want to move this code from my product (view.phtml) and call it from model/helper(?). What is the best approach and how to call my function inside view.phtml ?

Comment: did you create a module for that? add this function in your helper and get the collection Mage::helper('book')->urfunction();

Comment: No, i was thinking of using the catalog module, i'm just testing in a sample-data installation to get a sense of it.

Comment: then don't change in core module. that my suggestion for testing purpose get collection in view directly.

Comment: copy model file in from code/mage to core/local and make changes there it is best approach.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.
One last question : What are the best resources out there from beginners magento developers in your opinion ?

Answer (score 1):

you forgot an `echo` in this line:

```
<a href="<?php  $this->getUrl('books').$related->getUrlPath()."<br />";?>"><?php echo $related->getName();?></a>
```

it should be

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('books').$related->getUrlPath()."<br />";?>"><?php echo $related->getName();?></a>
```

Side note...
you should not generate the url like this `<?php echo $this->getUrl('books').$related->getUrlPath()."<br />"`

use `$related->getProductUrl()`